# Key event for ajax call does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am making an application where, when the user presses Enter, it should make an ajax call.

I used a plugin to browse the items and created jQuery code for the "click" (worked perfectly).

The problem is that when I make it so that pressing Enter calls the ajax code, there is some kind of conflict and it does not work.

Does anyone have any solution or another method?
thanks.

javascript

```
var main = function () {
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            // titulos
            var titles = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.title;

            });

            // urls
            var urls = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.origLink;

            });

            $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
            $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function (key, value) {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<a class="link-podcast" href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
            });

            // Load KeyNavigation
            a = $('.nav_holder li a').keynav(function () {
                return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
            });


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });


}(jQuery);

///

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Call Ajax Click  <-- work
    $('.container-list-podcast').on('click', '.link-podcast', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
    });

    // Call Ajax Key Enter <-- dont work
    $('.container-list-podcast').on('keypress', '.selected', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which == 13) { // keyCode 13 == Enter key
            $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
        }
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/11/)

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `main` on the keypress.

Comment: I did not understand, what is there main? I used the code and it worked like to click normal.

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML?  That may help.  Something has to trigger the function `main` when the user clicks or presses the ENTER key.

Comment: the main part of this this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/11/

Comment: Well I see one issue with the markup.  There is nothing inside the div with class `container-list-podcast` that has the class `link-podcast` or `selected`.  You are passing a selector to the jQuery on method and that selector is used to filter the selector you are calling on on :P  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the keypress event will not be triggered by an a element unless it has a focus. It would be more garantee to bind this event to the document.

Change your function to that:

```
// Call Ajax Key Enter
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {

    if (e.which == 13) { // keyCode 13 == Enter key
        $('.video').attr('src', $('.container-list-podcast .selected').prop('href'));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/11/)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted.  The answer above is functionally equivalent to the code posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('keydown', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();  
   if (e.which == 13) { // keyCode 13 == Enter key  
      $('.selected').trigger('click', function() {  
         $('.video').attr('src', this.href);  
      });  
    }  
});
```

You can try binding a keydown event to body or document it will full fill your purpose.